# Canvas versus DOM - What is the most efficient image display method in HTML5?

Tags: performance, html, canvas, image

StackOverflow users

While making a html5 application/website, for such cases as an image gallery, where a large number of images are displayed sequentially or at the same time in the browser, is the use of the canvas element justified?

As long as we are only talking about presenting an image, is there any point in using a canvas and drawing the image on it instead of using the DOM element < img > tag?
There will also be some image manipulation, like CSS3 transformations/moving/scaling/zooming and gesture recognition (drag, touch/tap, maybe pinch, etc.) which, as far as I know, are applicable to both the canvas and the img tags.

It would also be important to keep things as much "html5"-ish as possible and also taking performance into account.
For example, it would matter if in the future the canvas element will be more and more used and optimized by the browsers and it would also matter if for the time being the < img > is much faster.

Since we are considering developing an universal html5 application, working on desktops and also on mobile devices, performance and speed are a very important factor. However, the tests comparing canvas and < img > were targeting mostly javascript browser games. In this case, the animation is not that important as the memory consumption and overall performance.

Are there any resources/studies regarding this particular aspect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UseCanvas = NeedCanvas ? true : false
```

You really don't need canvas for this operation, and it will take longer to develop with canvas as it's a lot more complicated.

Using `<img>` tags with javascript will not only increase compatibility but speed and accessibility too - absolutely everything with a browser can run CSS and Javascript. Additionally there's SEO factors too, I'm pretty sure the images in a canvas won't get indexed.

Don't use HTML5 technology for the sake of using HTML5 technology. When you want to start warping the images and having the user draw on them so you can export/save, that's where you need canvas.

Comment: SEO is not really a factor here, only performance. I agree with what you said about not using HTML5 just for the sake of using it. Thing is I also have to take into account what might be helpful in the future and we all know html5 is the future. Of course, no one knows what the future holds but I noticed similar apps using canvas and it made me wonder why and if there is any advantage over the obvious use of < img >

Comment: @BogdanBucur - `img` is just as much HTML5 as `canvas` is! It was part of HTML4, an HTML5 builds on top of that. It is as much part of "the future" as anything else.

Comment: @BogdanBucur `<img>` is a fundamental part of HTML, it's not going anywhere **ever**. What you have described is a very simple image gallery, canvas is really for games, and unless you are building a complicated game with loops, physics, states etc, there really is no need at all to use it. I suggest you look at some jQuery examples to see it's power and you'll realise you don't need it for the effects you have mentioned.

Comment: lol, no, it's not about img becoming obsolete. What we actually need to do is more of an advanced catalog, the image gallery is a basic example of functionality. I looked at many examples and I've also used jQuery in the past, it's just that most of these examples were, as you said, mostly for games and not simpler cases, like mine.

Comment: In the scope of mobile development, I think this is a very important question.  If canvas elements somehow manage memory better than img elements, it would be a boon for mobile html5/js apps. I remember reading somewhere that canvas elements are able to use opengl to render(browser-dependent). I would think that OpenGL would have its own faster ways of handling memory than javascript. Currently OpenGL might not be prevalent on mobile devices but its something to consider.